# Add a hyperlink only to one column of a table

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table, multiple-columns

I have some query that extracts data from the database like this:

```
   |17DATE00   |concat(filename, fileextension) |
   |-----------|--------------------------------|
   |2017-05-30 |filename00000.pdf               |
   |2017-03-29 |filename00002.doc               |
```

Now for the second column, I have passed the link of the doc, so you can click on it and download it.

This is the way I extract the data

```
$header = array("17DATE00", "concat(filename, fileextension)");

echo "<thead><tr>";
foreach ($header as $list) {
    echo '<th >' . $list . '</th>';
}

echo "</thead></tr>";
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
    foreach ( $value as $a ) {
        $url = get_template_directory_uri();
        echo '<td><a href="'.$url.'/folder/' . $a . '">'. htmlspecialchars($a) .' </a></td>';
    }   
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Doing this, both columns get hyperlinked, while I only need the second one. 
Anyway to fix this?

Comment: Can you show the data in $query. print_r($query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a counter to you inner loop:

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ( $value as $a )
{
    $url = get_template_directory_uri();

    if ($counter == 1)
    {
        echo '<td><a href="'.$url.'/folder/' . $a . '">'. htmlspecialchars($a) .' </a></td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td>'. htmlspecialchars($a) .'</td>';
    }

    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: That works only when I have one row. But when I add a second one, it doesn't work

Comment: You have to reset the counter before you start generating the next row: `$counter = 0;`

Comment: By setting `$counter` to `0`: `$counter = 0;` This has to happen each time **before** you start generating the next row. So before output of `<tr>...`.

Answer (score 0):

You should print the link only if `$key == "concat(filename, fileextension)"`